# Postscript: How can I alias or substitute one font for another?

Tags: postscript

I want to check if the font exists and if it doesn't then substitute it for another and to make it work for every instance of the font in the document I can use: 
/font_a /Font resourcestatus dup { 3 1 roll pop pop } if {/font_a} {/font_b} ifelse findfont
but I need to use it each time I use font_a.
how to define it globally?

ps.sry for the broken english

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `findfont`/`scalefont`/`selectfont` throughout your document, define the fonts you'll use at the beginning of the file:

```
  /heading-font  /Helvetica-Bold findfont 14 scalefont def
  /body-font     /Times-Roman    findfont 11 scalefont def
  ...
  heading-font setfont (Trees) show
  body-font setfont  (A tree is a tall living structure made of wood.) show
  heading-font setfont (Lakes) show
  body-font setfont (A lake is a storage medium for water.) show
  ...
```

You will still have to search through the font resources to see if the typefaces you want are available, but you will only have to do it once per typeface.